# Dotnet Enviromental Variables No Admin Rights

Tags: windows-10

I have installed at my work PC (Windows 10) several dotnet runtimes.

I have no administration rights, but I want to install the dotnet 7 SDK.

I have tried to download the binaries and set the USER environmental variables, but they do not work (e.g. dotnet --info returns no SDKs installed).

Is there a way to install the SDK?

tried to set the DOTNET_ROOT to my user files where I have downloaded the Binaries, also have set the path to the path variables of the USER

Have successfully added java17 binaries and maven binaries, but dotnet just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First off all restart your PC, is probably that simple.

If restarting doesn't work, search **"Edit environment variables for your account"** on Windows.

Add the dotNet bin path folder to a new User Environment Variable, call that Variable like DOTNET.

Run the command bellow in a powershell terminal

```
Get-ChildItem Env:DOTNET
```

Restart your PC and try dotnet --info

Working with Environment Variables always needs restarting your PC to SO rebuild your new configs.

You can also do all that stuff by terminal Command Line, following the steps of that article: https://www.shellhacks.com/set-environment-variable-without-admin-rights-windows/

Comment: Tried that does not work. The problem is that I cannot affect the global environmental variables only the variables for my account, since I am not an administrator. Also on the system there are installed the dotnet runtimes, but I need the SDK 7.

Comment: Also restarted PC many times, have been searching for solution for a week, but still dotnet --info returns "no SDKs installed", but only the runtimes are installed (from the administrator).

Comment: You can also add User Environmental Variables to your System, just like you said it wont will be change anything in Global Level, but if you really need that working, try it on User Level. In theory it should be work the same way. Just in case, put your project outside of ADMIN scope too(In case he is there).